# How to style push notification by JSON with parse.com [Android]

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform, push

I wonder how to style push notifications on android phones using parse.com service. 
Which fields are available, and is there any possibility to style the color, image  and formats [bold, italic, ...] of the push notification?
Thank you

Comment: Just learn how to style notification in android for that, because whatever is pushed to your device from parse.com, will be shown in a style to the user as per the code(for notification) of your android app but not of parse.com push notification code.Refer [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_notifications.htm) to learn how to deal with android notifications.

Answer (score 0):

For Android push notifications, you can customize the following:

1. **alert:** the notification's message.
2. **action:** the Intent should be fired when the push is received. If no title or alert values are specified, the Intent will be fired but no notification will appear to the user.
3. **title:** the value displayed in the Android system tray or Windows 8 toast notification.

[Source](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android)

This [tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications) would probably be useful.

Comment: Is that possible to change the formatting of the text?! for example use italic style for headline and so on?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can Develop your own style
first : 
add custom push receiver in manifest Like blew :

```
<receiver android:name=".CustomPushReceiver" android:exported="false">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"/>
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE"/>
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE"/>
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN"/>
</intent-filter>
```

CustomPushReceiver:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver;

import mainViews.MainPage;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;



/**
 * Created by SadSad on 01/06/15.
 */
public class CustomPushReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
    private final String TAG = CustomPushReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

    private Intent parseIntent;

    public CustomPushReceiver() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushReceive(context, intent);

        System.out.println(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

        if (intent == null)
            return;

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

            System.out.println(json );

            Log.e(TAG, "Push received: " + json);

            parseIntent = intent;

            parsePushJson(context, json);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Push message json exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushDismiss(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushDismiss(context, intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushOpen(context, intent);
    }

    /**
     * Parses the push notification json
     *
     * @param context
     * @param json
     */
    private void parsePushJson(Context context, JSONObject json) {
        try {
            System.out.println(json);
            boolean isBackground = json.getBoolean("is_background");
            JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
            String title = data.getString("title");
            String message = data.getString("message");

            if (!isBackground) {
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainPage.class);
                showNotificationMessage(context, title, message, resultIntent);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Push message json exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    /**
     * Shows the notification message in the notification bar
     * If the app is in background, launches the app
     *
     * @param context
     * @param title
     * @param message
     * @param intent
     */
    private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, Intent intent) {

    // you can use custom notification 
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);

        intent.putExtras(parseIntent.getExtras());

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, intent);
    }
}
```

Custom Notification:
[This link is useful for custom notification](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html)